# Gutenberg Block language translation does not work

Tags: block-editor

I have created Gutenberg blocks for my shortcodes, below is some code:

The code in PHP file in init hook to load script:

```
wp_register_script(
    'my-blocks-script', $pluginurl . '/custom-blocks.js',
    array( 'wp-blocks', 'wp-components', 'wp-element', 'wp-i18n', 'wp-editor' ),
    filemtime( $plugindir . '/custom-blocks.js' )
);

// Script contains translations
if( function_exists('wp_set_script_translations') ) {
    wp_set_script_translations( 'my-blocks-script', 'my-text-domain' );
}

// Shortcode block
register_block_type( 'custom-block/my-shortcode', array(
    'editor_script' => 'my-blocks-script'
) );
```

JS code: file: custom-blocks.js

```
( function (blocks, editor, components, i18n, element ) {
    // Define common variables
    var el = wp.element.createElement;
    var registerBlockType = wp.blocks.registerBlockType;
    var InnerBlocks = wp.editor.InnerBlocks;
    var BlockControls = wp.editor.BlockControls;
    var Dashicon = wp.components.Dashicon;
    var __ = wp.i18n.__;

    // Shortcode
    registerBlockType( 'custom-block/my-shortcode', {
        title: __( 'Shortcode Title', 'my-text-domain' ),
        description: '',
        icon: Dashicon.cogs,
        category: 'common',
        attributes: {
            display: {
                type: 'boolean',
                default: true
            }
        },
        edit: function() {
            return [
                el( components.CheckboxControl, {
                    label: __( 'Display it?', 'my-text-domain' ),
                    checked: props.attributes.myAttr,
                    onChange: function( val ) {
                        props.setAttributes({ myAttr: val })
                    }
                } ),
            ];
        },
        save: function(props) {
            return(
                el('div', { className: props.className }, '[my-shortcode display="'+props.attributes.display+'"]' )
            );
        }
    } );

} ) (
    window.wp.blocks,
    window.wp.editor,
    window.wp.components,
    window.wp.i18n,
    window.wp.element
);
```

Everything works fine, blocks display result too. but now I want to translate "Display it?" text with another language ( I use Loco Translate plugin ), I have checked po file the translation string is there, also translated strings in PHP file works fine.

Here, only the JS file transition does not work.

Comment: Do you have `var i18n = wp.i18n` somewhere in your script or on the page? Because the translation library is `wp.i18n`.

Comment: @SallyCJ please check I have updated whole JS code.

Comment: Ok, but there's a syntax error here: `el('div', { className: props.className }, '[my-shortcode display='"+props.attributes.display+"']' )`

Comment: @SallyCJ Sorry it's by mistake here, but there is no JS error or no issue with functionality. the only issue is translation does not work.

Comment: Yes, I understand. But even just in the question, you should always avoid typos and syntax errors. It will greatly help others when testing your code. And there's another typo there: `edit: function()` should be `edit: function(props)`.

Comment: Anyway, check my answer and let me know how it goes.

Comment: From the LocoTranslate-FAQ: "Loco Translate does not currently generate JSON language packs for use with wp_set_script_translations. This is a known limitation and we're working to add support for it. Few products use this new feature without a fallback, so check with the vendor whether JSON language packs are required."
https://localise.biz/wordpress/plugin/faqs/not-showing

Answer (score 4):

> only the JS file translation does not work

It's most likely because WordPress couldn't find your translation file, which should be in a valid [JED](https://messageformat.github.io/Jed/) format, like so:

```
{
  "domain": "my-text-domain",
  "locale_data": {
    "my-text-domain": {
      "": {
        "domain":       "my-text-domain",
        "plural-forms": "n != 1",
        "lang":         "en-us"
      },
      "Shortcode Title": [
        "Shortcode Title translated"
      ],
      "Display it?": [
        "Display it? translated"
      ],
      "Another text 1": [
        "Translated text - singular",
        "Translated text - plural"
      ],
      "Another text 2": [
        "Translated text"
        // No plural.
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

And saved with a name in this format: `${domain}-${locale}-${handle}.json`. For example, in your case, it could be `my-text-domain-en_US-my-blocks-script.json` if the site's language is `English (United States)` (see "General Settings" → "Site Language").

And when you call `wp_set_script_translations()`, you can specify the third parameter ([`$path`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_script_translations/#parameters)) which is the full absolute file path to the directory containing the JS/JSON translation files. E.g.:

```
// $pluginurl was taken from your code
wp_set_script_translations( 'my-blocks-script', 'my-text-domain', $pluginurl . '/languages' );
```

Also, you can use [po2json](https://github.com/mikeedwards/po2json) to convert PO/`.po` files to a *JED-compatible* JavaScript object or JSON string.

**Notes:**

- In the above JS/JSON translation data, the locale as in `"lang": "{locale}"` should be the *GlotPress locale* as you can see in the table on [this page](https://make.wordpress.org/polyglots/teams/). For example, `en-gb` for `English (UK)`.
- In your JS/JSON translation *file name*, the locale as in `${domain}-${locale}-${handle}.json` should be the *WP locale* as you can see in the table on [this page](https://make.wordpress.org/polyglots/teams/). For example, `en_GB`for `English (UK)`.

Comment: Here, we need to provide translations with fixed languages, isn't a dynamic way? like loco translate scan the PHP ( also an option to scan JS files ) and generate POT file and add translations from the backend?

Comment: I think the original question has already been answered.. Nonetheless, in reply to that "dynamic way", you could use the [`pre_load_script_translations`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_load_script_translations/) or [`load_script_translations`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/load_script_translations/) filter - in your callback, you could parse your PO file and generate the JSON translations string, and return the string. You should also check [this post](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp_set_script_translations/#post-11065440).

Comment: Can you please saw any examples, how can I use those filters?